# Layout constraints with dynamic labels - UIView.animate

Tags: animation, layout

I have a label (myLabel) question that flies in, in my view dynamically with UIView.animate for each new question. On the right side of this label I have a text Field for the response of the user (myResponse). I want to have a 20 points constant distance (X distance) between both but via standard main.storyboard autolayout constraints it's not working consistently sometimes the distance is 20 sometimes around 50 (I used: leading space to Challenge = 20) I believe the issue is because my label is dynamically animated. After each question I reset the origin of my Challenge label. So to fix it I tried to add the distance between the label and the text field programmatically but without success. How to code in a simple manner?

The code of the animation is the following:

```
    myLabel.center.x = (self.view.frame.width/4)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        self.myLabelXConstraint.constant = self.myLabelXConstraint.constant + (0.1 * self.screenWidth)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
```

How to instruct by coding to have 20 points distance from myLabel and myText Field?

Comment: As I got no answer I tried again to solve this problem. I tried following (as reminder myLabel is a dynamic label entering in my view from the left side and horizontally, myResponse is the response the user needs to give and is a text field that should be always at 20 points on the right of myLabel). What I tried is following code:     override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()        
        myLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myResponse.leadingAnchor, constant: 20) } -> without success. If someone can help it would be highly appreciated

Comment: Again a new problem solved on my own (a pity that on my 6-7 last questions I never got an answer from this forum) - it took me again 5-6 hours of try and tests to solve it. Above command I added was almost correct but missing a .isActive = true at the end (was difficult to find as I had no errors on this command). So the correct complete command was: myLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myResponse.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true